# Retrieving items from a dictionary data type created from a JSON request

Tags: python, json

I've tried every way I can find to loop through the member items in the JSON returned below by this code:

```
import requests,string,simplejson as json
from pprint import pprint

data=requests.get('http://localhost:8090/api/v1/members/2321')
data  = json.loads(data.text)

pprint(data)
```

The results of this pprint are:

```
{u'members': [[{u'member_amt_pledged': u'10.00',
u'member_amt_recvd': None,
u'member_id': u'1',
u'name': u'Murray Hight'},
{u'member_amt_pledged': u'10.00',
u'member_amt_recvd': None,
u'member_id': u'4',
u'name': u'Martin Tunis'}]],
u'error': False}
```

How can I loop through this data member data and evaluate and print each line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` in your code is a python [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). A key value pair.

You can access items in a dictionary with a `variable[key]` format. In your case as:

```
data['members']
```

this prints

```
[[{u'member_amt_pledged': u'10.00',
   u'member_amt_recvd': None,
   u'member_id': u'1',
   u'name': u'Murray Hight'},
  {u'member_amt_pledged': u'10.00',
   u'member_amt_recvd': None,
   u'member_id': u'4',
   u'name': u'Martin Tunis'}]]
```

so `data['members']` is a list of a list. Access it's first item as `data['members'][0]`. This is still a list. So you iterate over it as:

```
for item in data['members'][0]:
    print(item)
```

this gives you:

```
{u'member_amt_recvd': None, u'member_amt_pledged': u'10.00', u'name': u'Murray Hight', u'member_id': u'1'}
{u'member_amt_recvd': None, u'member_amt_pledged': u'10.00', u'name': u'Martin Tunis', u'member_id': u'4'}
```

As you can see, each of these are dictionaries, so you access it's items as:

```
for item in data['members'][0]:
    print(item['member_amt_pledged'])
    print(item['member_amt_recvd'])
    print(item['member_id'])
    print(item['name'])
```

this gives you:

```
10.00
None
1
Murray Hight
10.00
None
4
Martin Tunis
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thank you so much for your incredibly thorough and well written response.

Answer (score 0):

To loop the items of the `JSON` dictionary, you would do the following:

```
for key, val in data.items():
    print key, val
```

For a larger dataset, you should use iterators:

```
for key, val in data.iteritems(): 
    print key, val
```

[More on dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)