# Creating lists and dictionaries from JSON data in Python

Tags: python, json, list, rest, dictionary

I am writing a script to collect some inventory data via REST. I then want to filter it to create a list and two dictionaries which I can use elsewhere in my script.

For example, from this:

```
{'version': '0.0'
 'response': [{'chassisType': 'C800',
           'family': 'C897VA-K9',
           'hostname': 'chaney-xtr',
           'imageName': 'c800-universalk9-mz.SPA.154-2.T.bin',
           'interfaceCount': '10',
           'lastUpdated': '2014-06-03 01:39:19.855491-07',
           'lineCardId': 'e5bddd56-2194-4b83-8ae5-597893800051',
           'macAddress': '88:5A:92:A4:E7:C8',
           'managementIpAddress': '192.168.2.1',
           'memorySize': '988236K/60339K',
           'networkDeviceId': 'e15789bd-47df-4df9-809f-daf81d15ff2a',
           'numUpdates': 1,
           'platformId': 'C897VA-K9',
           'portRange': 'ATM0, ATM0.1, BRI0, BRI0:1-2, Dialer1, Ethernet0, GigabitEthernet0-8, LISP0, Loopback0-1, NVI0, Virtual-Access1, Virtual-Template1, Vlan1',
           'role': 'Unknown',
           'roleSource': 'auto',
           'serialNumber': 'FGL175124DX',
           'softwareVersion': '15.4(2)T',
           'type': 'UNKNOWN',
           'upTime': '2 weeks, 3 days, 18 hours, 2 minutes',
           'vendor': 'Cisco'},
          {'chassisType': 'C800',
           'family': 'C897VA-K9',
           'hostname': 'chaney-xtr2',
           'imageName': 'c800-universalk9-mz.SPA.154-2.T.bin',
           'interfaceCount': '10',
           'lastUpdated': '2014-06-03 01:39:19.855491-07',
           'lineCardId': 'e5bddd56-2194-4b83-8ae5-597893800051',
           'macAddress': '88:5A:92:A4:E7:C8',
           'managementIpAddress': '192.168.2.2',
           'memorySize': '988236K/60339K',
           'networkDeviceId': 'e15789bd-47df-4df9-809f-daf81d15ff2a',
           'numUpdates': 1,
           'platformId': 'C897VA-K9',
           'portRange': 'ATM0, ATM0.1, BRI0, BRI0:1-2, Dialer1, Ethernet0, GigabitEthernet0-8, LISP0, Loopback0-1, NVI0, Virtual-Access1, Virtual-Template1, Vlan1',
           'role': 'Unknown',
           'roleSource': 'auto',
           'serialNumber': 'XGL175124D3',
           'softwareVersion': '15.4(2)T',
           'type': 'UNKNOWN',
           'upTime': '2 weeks, 3 days, 18 hours, 2 minutes',
           'vendor': 'Cisco'}],
 }
```

where `"platformId" = "C897VA-K9"` I want to create a list of IP addresses from `managementIpAddress`

And two dictionaries using IP address as key

```
dict1 = {"managementIpAddress": "hostname"}
dict2 = {"managementIpAddress": "platformId"}
```

How would you go about doing this?

Kind regards,

Ryan

Comment: What approaches have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried the python docs? https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: As @cwallenpoole mentioned, you should share what you've tried doing so far, and where specifically you got stuck with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from_this = {"version":"0.0","response":[{"macAddress":"88:5A:92:A4:E7:C8","networkDeviceId":"e15789bd-47df-4df9-809f-daf81d15ff2a","lineCardId":"e5bddd56-2194-4b83-8ae5-597893800051","lastUpdated":"2014-06-03 01:39:19.855491-07","platformId":"C897VA-K9","vendor":"Cisco","numUpdates":1,"interfaceCount":"10","portRange":"ATM0, ATM0.1, BRI0, BRI0:1-2, Dialer1, Ethernet0, GigabitEthernet0-8, LISP0, Loopback0-1, NVI0, Virtual-Access1, Virtual-Template1, Vlan1","roleSource":"auto","chassisType":"C800","softwareVersion":"15.4(2)T","upTime":"2 weeks, 3 days, 18 hours, 2 minutes","imageName":"c800-universalk9-mz.SPA.154-2.T.bin","memorySize":"988236K/60339K","managementIpAddress":"192.168.2.1","family":"C897VA-K9","type":"UNKNOWN","serialNumber":"FGL175124DX","role":"Unknown","hostname":"chaney-xtr"}, {"macAddress":"88:5A:92:A4:E7:C8","networkDeviceId":"e15789bd-47df-4df9-809f-daf81d15ff2a","lineCardId":"e5bddd56-2194-4b83-8ae5-597893800051","lastUpdated":"2014-06-03 01:39:19.855491-07","platformId":"C897VA-K9","vendor":"Cisco","numUpdates":1,"interfaceCount":"10","portRange":"ATM0, ATM0.1, BRI0, BRI0:1-2, Dialer1, Ethernet0, GigabitEthernet0-8, LISP0, Loopback0-1, NVI0, Virtual-Access1, Virtual-Template1, Vlan1","roleSource":"auto","chassisType":"C800","softwareVersion":"15.4(2)T","upTime":"2 weeks, 3 days, 18 hours, 2 minutes","imageName":"c800-universalk9-mz.SPA.154-2.T.bin","memorySize":"988236K/60339K","managementIpAddress":"192.168.2.2","family":"C897VA-K9","type":"UNKNOWN","serialNumber":"XGL175124D3","role":"Unknown","hostname":"chaney-xtr2"}]}

dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}

for response_item in from_this['response']:
    dict1[response_item['managementIpAddress']] = response_item['hostname']
    dict2[response_item['managementIpAddress']] = response_item['platformId']
```

The output looks like this:

```
In[189]: dict1
Out[187]: {'192.168.2.1': 'chaney-xtr', '192.168.2.2': 'chaney-xtr2'}
In[190]: dict2
Out[188]: {'192.168.2.1': 'C897VA-K9', '192.168.2.2': 'C897VA-K9'}
```

If this is what you were looking for, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Wow! That was fast. Thanks Krishan that's very helpful.

For those who asked, I find the Python documentation hard to follow however I did find this answer on this site which was also very helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024477/retrieving-items-from-a-dictionary-data-type-created-from-a-json-request.

Answer (score 0):

you can parse the json data,then add some if and else case to judge whether data is needed;then use eval statement to gengerate a dict

Comment: Your answer will be clearer if you expand on it and supply example code